# SQL 2014 sp_send_dbmail 64KB query result limit?

Tags: sql-server-2014, sp-send-dbmail

Calling sp_send_dbmail using the @query option to run a query and use the result as the email body, appears to cut off the resultset at around 64KB maximum, regardless of the mail configuration settings. I have also tried attaching the result as a file attachment to the email, but am having the same problem there as well - the file attachment caps itself around 64KB.

Anyone has a solution or workaround for that problem?

Comment: Looks like it remains an open bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/850260/sql-2014-sp-send-dbmail-64kb-query-result-limit  

I'm running into the same issue with no safe workaround yet, but I'll post back if I come up with something.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by Microsoft in CU4 (Cumulative Update) for SQL Serve 2014. Please follow this link in order to obtain the file:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2999197

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug in the SQL Server 2014 version of XPStar.dll.

My workaround was to copy the file from a 2012 instance and replace the 2014 one. After a restart the attachment works properly.